# Windows Server 2016 - L2TP VPN local network issuse

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server-2016, l2tp

we configured VPN access to our server via L2TP with preshared key to tunnel our RDP admin connection. Everything works fine if we need to just connect to the server - We are behind NAT from out ISP Router we used NAT-Traversal modification for client to server connection but right now we were asked if we can establish connections for other users to local network.
Our network works on 192.168.0.0/24 subnet and VPN works on 10.0.0.0/24 -  connecting with checked "use default gateway on remote network" will drop the internet connection on client PC - only VPN server is reachable in local network with this checked.
If we uncheck it we have VPN with client internet but we lose connection to server via local network (via vpn ip address still works fine) - in unchecked scenario we can use cmd: route -p add 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1 and with this we have internet and access to server via its local address but other PC in local network are still unreachable ...

What are we messed up or missed? Is there more elegant way of doing something like this (without additional hardware)